# Stata: Linear Regression With Over 11,000 Dummy Variables

Tags: regression, stata, dummy-data

I'm trying to run a panel regression with over 11,000 dummy interaction terms. My regression looks like this:

```
xi: reg Y i.county*i.year
```

where `i.county*i.year` represents interaction of dummy variables. Neither Stata, nor Matlab, nor R will hold this many variables. I'm not sure if there's a command to increase the number of variables stored (e.g. a -set matsize- command in stata) that I am missing.

I do know that the max capacity for Stata matrices is 11,000 variables. How can I run this fixed-effects regression in Stata? Is Mata an option here?

Comment: How would you interpret these results? Are there other regressors `X`? If so, I suggest manually doing the within estimator by demeaning using `collapse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other regressors then Richard Herron's suggestion to use `collapse` in the comment is probably the best way to do this. If you do have other regressors then your model is just a fixed effects model where your groupping variable is just country-year. You can than estimate your model by typing

```
egen id = group(country year)
xtset id
xtreg y x1 x2, fe
```

alternatively:

```
egen id = group(country year)
areg y x1 x2, absorb(id)
```

The difference between these two is discussed in the helpfile of `areg`. The relevant section is "`areg` is designed for datasets with many groups, but not a number of groups that increases with the sample size.  See the `xtreg, fe` command for an estimator that handles the case in which the number of groups increases with the sample size."

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you can't use a random effects model here?
Stata/SE allows you to increase the maximum number of variables (set maxvar) but still, a regression model with 11,000 fixed effects and an interaction term will likely blow the top off of your computer...